# PHP file-writing problems

Tags: php

I have a file called "number.txt"(there is a number inside, e.g.: 0 )
And I want to read the number inside the number.txt and use fwrite to write the number plus 1
(number+1), so that each time anyone visit this webpage, the number will add 1.

but when i test it, it only works at first time(now number.txt is 1).
Then i try another time, the fread function read 0 but not 1.

```
<?php
    $fgc = file_get_contents('number.txt');
    settype($cont, "integer");
    $cont = $cont + 1;
    settype($cont, "string");
    file_put_contents('number.txt', $cont);
    $str = settype($cont, "string");
    $fp = fopen( $str ,'w+');

    if($fp==false) {
        $str = $str + 1;
        $fp = fopen( $str ,'w+');
    }

    if($fp==false) {
        $str = $str + 1;
        $fp = fopen( $str ,'w+');
    }

    if($fp==false) {
        $str = $str + 1;
        $fp = fopen( $str ,'w+');
    }

    if($fp==false) {
        $str = $str + 1;
        $fp = fopen( $str ,'w+');
    }

    $da = $_GET['data'];

    fwrite($fp, $da);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And why not to do simple like this:

```
file_put_contents('numbers.txt', is_writeable('numbers.txt')?((int)file_get_contents('numbers.txt'))+1:exit('Failed to open file'));
```

Comment: This is a good one-liner, however your code will produce an error if the file does not exist. I suggest you mention that in your answer, and/or use a function that will create the file (if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Yes, and that is why I've formed my one-lined code as a question (author did not mentioned special cases - when file is absent or inaccessible)

Comment: I understand, and you're right. I borrowed your idea and wrote a script and will post it as an answer, and mention you in a credit, based on your idea. :) +1 by the way, cheers

Comment: Updated as you've mentioned

Comment: Right on Eugene, kudos ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing on [**Eugene's great one-liner**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18080692/1415724), came up with the following solution.

(Credit goes to go [Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637490/eugene))

The following code will create the file if it does not exist, and increment by +1 each time it is reloaded.

(Tested)

```
<?php

$filename = "number.txt";
$filename = fopen($filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");

file_put_contents('number.txt', ((int)file_get_contents('number.txt'))+1);

// To show (echo) the contents of the file, you can use one of the following
// include("number.txt");
// echo file_get_contents('number.txt'); 

?>
```

Comment: I think the code with error handling can be written as: file_put_contents('number.txt', is_writeable('numbers.txt')?((int)file_get_contents('number.txt'))+1:exit('Could not open file'))

Comment: @Eugene I got the following error message using that `Warning: file_get_contents(number.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in....`

Comment: @Eugene **"Scratch that"** my bad. Yes you're right, it does work. I had something else happening.

Comment: Hm. May be because I mistyped? (In my sample in comment I've checking is_writeable('numbers.txt') and file_get_contents('number.txt')). Also, perhaps, @ can be used here. Any way, it is not a good practice, I think. Better to throw an exception separately. Short code is not always a good code.

Comment: @Eugene You should update/edit your answer, it's a good one. See my edited comment just above yours here.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are setting the write data to the old GET var and not the new set var.

```
fwrite($fp, $da);
```

Try using

```
fwrite($fp, $str);
```

And also you only need to fopen() once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'number.txt';
$content = (int) file_get_contents($filename);
$content++;
var_dump($content);
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

You have to create that file number.txt and insert there 0 as file content, then your script should work every time.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the contents into the variable $fgc, but you're trying to use $cont to represent that value, which is uninitialized.  So your settype call is going to cast that to 0.  Instead, try:

```
$fgc = file_get_contents('number.txt');
settype($fgc, "integer");
```